# Using Blur.js for a glossy background for a div does not work when page is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blur

I am using blur.js to give a glossy blur effect to an element in my html document.  The problem is that it works only when the background size is covered. as soon as I re-size or load the page in a different size of screen, it messes up. Since blur.js does not work on JSfiddel, I could not show you a demo, but have a look at the code and the image plz.

[image]

**CSS:**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:url('../img/spiral_galaxy-1920x1080.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
}
```

**BODY**

```
<div class="centered">text</div>

<script src="js/interactive.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.centered').blurjs({
                overlay: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
                radius:20
            });
        });
 </script>
```

Is there any way to keep it still blured in any size of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your screen size probably matches the size of the image: that is a coincidence only and that is why you don't see any problems with `background-size: cover;` when in fullscreen.

blur.js will set the background of the `.centered` div with a base64 portion of the background image in its **normal size**, it will not compensate the resizing the background image is suffering. With `background-size: cover;` the image is always being resized to fit the size of the div that it is a background of.

> Is there any way to keep it still blured in any size of the screen?

It is always blurred so I assume you meant keeping it blurred with a blur that matches the background underneath. That can only be done without `background-size: cover;`.

You probably know this but to keep the blurred background updated when resizing you could do this:

`$( window ).resize(function() {
    $('.centered').blurjs({
        source: 'body',
        overlay: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        radius:20 
    });
});`

It is quite heavy though so be warned.